# Benchmarking MoveIt: unable to connect to database

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm trying to benchmark the different OMPL algorithms by using the official [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/benchmarking/benchmarking_tutorial.html?highlight=benchmark), however I cannot connect to the database.

As I am launching the panda arm with the db turned on through this command:

**roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch db:=true**

I get the following error:

**[ERROR] [1642350646.192738964]: Unable to connect to the database at 'localhost:33829'. If you just created the database, it could take a while for initial setup.**

I've seen a solution posted in [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/304528/moveit-benchmarking-cannot-connect-to-warehouse-database/), however that was for melodic while I'm on Noetic. As far as I've seen, there is no mongodb_store for Noetic, hence this solution didn't work for me.

I have installed ros mongodb via this command:

**sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-warehouse-ros-mongo**

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Could it be that I'm missing some files or maybe they need additional setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394438/benchmarking-moveit:-unable-to-connect-to-database/) by [Zero1d](https://answers.ros.org/users/93796/zero1d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-01-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-19**:
Have you reviewed this [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/persistent_scenes_and_states/persistent_scenes_and_states.html?highlight=mongodb)  ?

**Comment by [Zero1d](https://answers.ros.org/users/93796/zero1d/) on 2022-01-22**:
Yes I have. I installed ros_mongo for ros noetic and used the default suggested host and port. The error persists.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-22**:
Please take a look at this tread: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/123#issuecomment-797582356

```
sudo apt install mongodb-server-core
sudo apt install ros-noetic-warehouse-ros
# Not sure if the command below is needed...
sudo apt install ros-noetic-warehouse-ros-mongo
```

Plus there is more things to try that may help.
Let me know if it works to add as an answer.

**Comment by [Zero1d](https://answers.ros.org/users/93796/zero1d/) on 2022-01-23**:
Thank you osilva, your solution allowed me to connect to the database!

I'm new to the forums, so can you tell me if it's I that have to add the solution as the one that worked (and if it's so then how) or if it's something that you do yourself.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-23**:
Hi @Zero1d, the idea is to document the solution in the form of an answer. You may answer your own questions as well. To accept the answer pls check on the check mark so others know it worked for you. And you may also vote the question up to give karma to the answerer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1642350646.192738964]: Unable to connect to the database at 'localhost:33829'. If you just created the database, it could take a while for initial setup.
```

Likely cause is missing dependencies. Install the following:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-server-core
sudo apt install ros-noetic-warehouse-ros
# Not sure if the command below is needed...
sudo apt install ros-noetic-warehouse-ros-mongo
```

To verify mongod is working:

```
mongod -v
```

If the following error appears:

```
[ERROR] [1615567759.671633]: Mongo process exited with error code 100
```

That is because you have forgotten to kill your `roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch db:=true`

The suggested solution comes from this thread: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/123#issuecomment-797582356

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2022-09-07**:
FYI, the need for manually installing `mongodb-server-core` is explained in https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros_mongo/issues/31